# Absolute value inequality general case

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

By definition of absolute value, $|x|=a$ becomes $x=±a$,  $a>0$

With $|x| < a$ however, why does this no longer happen as $x < ±a$ is no longer true, and that it instead becomes $-a < x < a$?

Also, I really need to understand how modulus function works, so could explanations be detailed? Thanks very much!

Comment: $-a<x<a$ it's an interval. But what is it  $x<\pm a$? It's interesting that $|f(x)|<g(x)$ is equal to $-g(x)<f(x)<g(x)$ for all cases even for case when $g(x)<0$.

Comment: That is the question I'm asking: by definition since |x| = a becomes x=±a, shouldn't |x| < a become x < ±a? I know that is incorrect but why?

Comment: See my previous comment. What is it $x<\pm a$? Try to think about this thing.

Comment: that means that x< a or x<-a right?

Comment: Firstly, why not $x<a$ and $x<-a$? By the way $-a<x<a$ it's something another. $x<a$ or $x<-a$ it's $x<a$ only.

Comment: By definition $|a|$ it's a distance between  $a$ and the origin. Thus, for $a\geq0$  $|x|=a$ happens for $x=a$ or $x=-a$. Also $|x|<a$ happens for $-a<x<a$. Draw it!

Comment: ohh right after drawing it I understand. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition:
$$|x|=a, a>0 \Rightarrow \pm x=a \Rightarrow x= -a \ or \ x=a.$$
Similarly:
$$|x|<a, a>0 \Rightarrow \pm x<a \Rightarrow -x<a \ and \ x<a \Rightarrow x>-a \ and \ x<a.$$
Also:
$$|x|>a, a>0 \Rightarrow \pm x> a \Rightarrow -x>a \ or \ x>a \Rightarrow x<-a \ or \ x>a.$$
Alternatively, the inequalities can be squared to be solved by the method of intervals and to be explained why $and$ and $or$.

Answer (score 0):

For real $x,y$, regarded as points on the number line, 
$$|x-y|=\text{the distance from $x$ to $y$ (or equivalently, from $y$ to $x$)}$$
As a special case, using $y=0$,
$$|x| = \text{the distance from $x$ to $0$}$$

Now fix $a > 0$.

Using the distance interpretation of absolute value,
\begin{align*}
&|x| > a\\[3pt]
\iff\;&\text{The distance from $x$ to $0$ is greater than $a$}\\[-1pt]
&\text{(i.e., $x$ is more then $a$ away from the origin).}\\[3pt]
\iff\;&x < -a\;\;\text{or}\;\;x > a\\[10pt]
&\text{Analogously,}\\[4pt]
&|x| < a\\[3pt]
\iff\;&\text{The distance from $x$ to $0$ is less than $a$}\\[-1pt]
&\text{(i.e., $x$ is less then $a$ away from the origin).}\\[3pt]
\iff\;&-a < x < a\\[3pt]
\end{align*}

Thus, the distance interpretation justifies the algebraic results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion arises due to the idea that for $a > 0$, $|x|=a$ "becomes" $x= \pm{a}$.

I think it will help to say, for $a > 0$, $|x|=a$ is true if and only if either $x= -a$ or $x = a$.

For $a>0$.

Informally, the inequality $|x|<a$ is true if and only if $x$ is closer to $0$ than the numbers whose modulus (absolute value) is $a$.

Better, the inequality $|x|<a$ is true if and only if $x$ is closer to $0$ than the solutions to $|x|=a$.

Finally, the inequality $|x|<a$ is true if and only if $-a<x<a$.